# How to insert content from a different file at the end of a particular heading anywhere in the document? vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

My objective is to insert content form a different file at the end of particular section that is titled "Terms and Conditions" with H1 heading style applied.

The doc structure is as follows:

```
Exec Summary

Solution Overview

Terms and Conditions

Why Us
```

Now the following Word VBA code inserts content from a different file at the end of "Terms and Conditions" regardless of where my cursor is located.

```
Sub insert_doc3()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fileName As String
    
    ' Set the file path of the document containing the content to be inserted
    fileName = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\NCC.docx"
    
    ' Assign the current document to the 'doc' variable
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Find the specified heading in the document
    Set rng = doc.Range
    With rng.Find
        .text = "Terms and Conditions"
        .Style = wdStyleHeading1
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute
    End With
    
    ' Check if the heading is found
    If rng.Find.Found Then
        ' Move the range to the end of the found heading
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        ' Enter a line break and redefine the range to its endpoint
        rng.InsertAfter text:=vbCr
        rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ' Insert the content from the external file
        rng.InsertFile fileName
    Else
        MsgBox "Heading not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above works just fine, but if I have a document that has a variations of the Terms and Conditions headings as follows, it doesn't quite work.

```
Exec Summary

Solution Overview

Terms and Conditions of Sale

Why Us
```

In this case, the content from the new file is inserted after "Terms and Conditions" with "of Sale" following the inserted content, as follows:

```
Exec Summary

Solution Overview

Terms and Conditions 

<NEW CONTENT>

of Sale

Why Us
```

How can I fix this so that the content is only inserted if the section is titled "Terms and Conditions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub insert_doc3()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fileName As String
    
    ' Set the file path of the document containing the content to be inserted
    fileName = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\NCC.docx"
    
    ' Assign the current document to the 'doc' variable
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Find the specified heading in the document
    Set rng = doc.Range
    rng.Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Terms and Conditions"
        .Style = wdStyleHeading1
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute
    End With
    
    ' Check if the heading is found
    If Selection.Find.Found Then
        ' Move the range to the end of the found heading
        Selection.Expand wdParagraph    'inserted
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        ' Enter a line break and redefine the range to its endpoint
        Selection.InsertAfter Text:=vbCr
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ' Insert the content from the external file
        Selection.InsertFile fileName
    Else
        MsgBox "Heading not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

Expanding the selection for the paragraph include the full header.

Comment: I did use `Selection.Expand wdParagraph` but it still leads to the same output. For example:

```
Exec Summary

Solution Overview

Terms and Conditions 

<NEW CONTENT>

of Sale

Why Us
```

Comment: @nosail did you change all `rng` to `selection` and add the `rng.select` line also as in the answer? I suggest for test copy the complete code for testing.

Comment: I did now and it works perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

### Try searching for the paragraph mark as well.

```
Sub insert_doc3()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fileName As String
    
    ' Set the file path of the document containing the content to be inserted
    fileName = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\NCC.docx"
    
    ' Assign the current document to the 'doc' variable
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Find the specified heading in the document
    Set rng = doc.Range
    With rng.Find
        .text = "Terms and Conditions^p"
        .Style = wdStyleHeading1
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute
    End With
    
    ' Check if the heading is found
    If rng.Find.Found Then
        ' Move the range to the end of the found heading
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        ' Enter a line break and redefine the range to its endpoint
        ' rng.InsertAfter text:=vbCr -- **commented out because already in range**
        rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ' Insert the content from the external file
        rng.InsertFile fileName
    Else
        MsgBox "Heading not found."
    End If
    ' CLEAN UP OBJECT VARIABLES
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

### Consider instead of a separate document, an AutoText Entry (or other building block) stored in a [template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm).

This makes the solution much more portable. Here are some links to my chapter on Automated Boilerplate:

- [AutoText](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete)
- [VBA to Insert AutoText or Building Blocks](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock)
- [Where can Building Blocks be stored?](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks)

Or, rather than using vba to insert it, you could simply put an AutoText Field in your template to call it into your document.

- [AutoText Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/47082137-225a-4d9e-b74a-5faf6a5f69cb)
  If your document will be going in Word form to someone else, you would want to unlink the field before sending.

An AutoText entry/Building Block entry is edited by inserting it into a document, making the changes, and then resaving the entry in the same [template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) using the same category and name.

*A *[template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm)* is a special kind of Word file with a .dotx or .dotm filename extension. It is not simply a sample document in Word jargon.*

Comment: Thank you, Charles. Let me try this approach. But i cannot use building blocks or auto-text fields because the content that i am pulling in from a different file is not owned by me and the content is subject to change.